# VBA Conditional Cells for SendKeys

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a VBA script that opens a PDF file and fills in the PDF based on cell info and then saves it, and moves onto the next cell within range.

I am trying to flag cells that have had a PDF created for them and have the code skip passed it in order to reduce time waiting, considering I have hundreds of cells.

This is my current code without any conditional lines.

I am looking to condition the below running on there being a value in column 17, and if it runs, to put a value in column 17 as a flag.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
For CustRow = 3 To 3 'LastRow

LastName = .Range("A" & CustRow).Value 'Name
Docket = .Range("B" & CustRow).Value 'Docket
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys .Range("H1").Value, True 'Today's Date
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001

Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys .Range("B1").Value, True 'ADA Name
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("M" & CustRow).Value, True 'Date of Offense
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("C" & CustRow).Value, True 'CC Number
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("N" & CustRow).Value, True 'Location
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("A" & CustRow).Value, True 'Defendant
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("B" & CustRow).Value, True 'Docket
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("E" & CustRow).Value, True 'Docket
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("B1").Value, True 'ADA Name
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys "+^(s)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
'Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
'Application.SendKeys .Range("A" & CustRow).Value, True 'Defendant Name

If Dir(SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & "_" & Docket & ".pdf") <> Empty Then Kill (SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & "_" & Docket & ".pdf")
'Application.SendKeys "%(n)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys "File name", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & "_" & Docket & ".pdf", True
Application.Wait Now + 0#
Application.SendKeys "%(s)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002


Next CustRow
Application.SendKeys "^(q)", True
Application.SendKeys "{numlock}%s", True

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA summarizes `End If`, `End With`, `Next` and `Loop` and flags the last one if the sum doesn't add up with the preceding `If`, `With`, `For` or `Do`. The cause for the wrong total may be anywhere before the flag. That's why one should indent everything between `If` and `End If`, `For` and `Next`, `Do` and `Loop` and `With` and `End With`. The indentation provides a visual check. Your code has no indentations. Therefore finding the missing `End` is much harder than it should be.

Comment: I updated the code to not have any of the poorly done conditions that I added.

I am essentially looking at how to properly condition this on there being a value in column 17, and then add a value into column 17 if it runs.

Comment: The post has also been updated.  This current code runs, and fills out the PDF for all rows that are flagged to run, but there currently is no flag to stop a row from having the same PDF created if the macro is run repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the below.  I was overthinking it.

```
For CustRow = 3 To 3 'LastRow
 If Trim(Cells(CustRow, 17).Value) = "" Then

LastName = .Range("A" & CustRow).Value 'Name
Docket = .Range("B" & CustRow).Value 'Docket
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys .Range("H1").Value, True 'Today's Date
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001

Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys .Range("B1").Value, True 'ADA Name
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("M" & CustRow).Value, True 'Date of Offense
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("C" & CustRow).Value, True 'CC Number
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("O" & CustRow).Value, True 'Location
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("A" & CustRow).Value, True 'Defendant
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("B" & CustRow).Value, True 'Docket
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("E" & CustRow).Value, True 'Docket
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("B1").Value, True 'ADA Name
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys "+^(s)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
'Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
'Application.SendKeys .Range("A" & CustRow).Value, True 'Defendant Name

If Dir(SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & "_" & Docket & ".pdf") <> Empty Then Kill (SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & "_" & Docket & ".pdf")
'Application.SendKeys "%(n)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys "File name", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & "_" & Docket & ".pdf", True
Application.Wait Now + 0#
Application.SendKeys "%(s)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002

Cells(CustRow, 17) = "Yes"

End If

Next CustRow
Application.SendKeys "^(q)", True
Application.SendKeys "{numlock}%s", True

End With
End Sub

Sub CreatePDFFormsBWC()
Dim PDFTemplateFile, NewPDFName, SavePDFFolder, LastName, Docket, BWCTemplateFile As String
Dim NCD As Date
Dim CustRow, LastRow, i As Long
With Sheet1
If .Range("Z1").Value = Empty Or .Range("AC1").Value = Empty Or .Range("Z2").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Both PDF Template and Saved PDF Locations are required for macro to run"
    Exit Sub
End If

LastRow = .Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Last Row
PDFTemplateFile = .Range("Z1").Value '911 Template File Name
SavePDFFolder = .Range("AC1").Value 'Save PDF Folder
BWCTemplateFile = .Range("Z2").Value 'BWC Template File
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink BWCTemplateFile
Application.Wait Now + 0.00006


For CustRow = 3 To 3 'LastRow
 If Trim(Cells(CustRow, 18).Value) = "" Then

LastName = .Range("A" & CustRow).Value 'Name
Docket = .Range("B" & CustRow).Value 'Docket

Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys .Range("P" & CustRow).Value, True 'Officers
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("M" & CustRow).Value, True 'Date of Offense
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("N" & CustRow).Value, True 'Time of Offense
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("C" & CustRow).Value, True 'CC
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("O" & CustRow).Value, True 'Location
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001

Application.SendKeys "+^(s)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
'Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
'Application.SendKeys .Range("A" & CustRow).Value, True 'Defendant Name

If Dir(SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & "_" & Docket & ".pdf") <> Empty Then Kill (SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & "_" & Docket & ".pdf")
'Application.SendKeys "%(n)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys "File name", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & "_" & Docket & ".pdf", True
Application.Wait Now + 0#
Application.SendKeys "%(s)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
    
Cells(CustRow, 18) = "Yes"

End If
    
Next CustRow
Application.SendKeys "^(q)", True
Application.SendKeys "{numlock}%s", True

End With
```